# Scroll slowly to 100%

Tags: jquery, css

I try to click to a button and scroll.I can do it easily with html (option 1). But it jumps and I would like to control the speed to move slowly.

Then I tried jQuery (Option1) but I do not know how to tell to scroll 100% of the window and how to control the speed. Is it possible to do that with css or/and jQuery?

Option 1. Scroll with HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/VPT4q/

```
<div id="first">
    <a href="#second">
        <div id="down"></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="second"></div>
```

Option 2. Scroll with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/VPT4q/1/

```
$(function(){      
    $('#down').click(function() {
        // window.scrollBy(0,200);
        window.scrollTo(0,200);
    });
})
```

Comment: the higher the number, the slower it goes in your javascript

Comment: @keith (0,200) the first number is the x and the second is the y (number of px) not the speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to do jQuery, I'd do it something like this:

```
$('#down').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#second').offset().top},'slow');
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gJwUT/

May not be exactly what you want, but I think it will get you started.

You can tweak the speed by changing `'slow'` to a number. `'slow'`, I think, is 1 second. or `'1000'`.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#second').offset().top}, 2000 );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#down').click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').height() }, 1000);
});
```

//1000 is number of milliseconds

Comment: Hmm. Did I misunderstand? Is the button meant to scroll to the top of the page or to where the div is?